# How to go to tab-number 1 when tab-end instead of going to next post?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form in MS Access 2007. To change from one inputfield to another the user can use tab or enter. The problem is when the user is in the last field and hit tab or enter she will jump to the next post. But I want to change this so the user jumps to the first filed in the same post or stays in the last field of the same post.

Maybe there is a very simple way to do this or do I have to write some vba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to set the Cycle property to Current Record (Other tab on form properties), the default is All Records.